# Is it possible to force authentication for in-app purchases using Google Play billing system?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-billing

We're currently working on our Android app's update to match the requirements of Google Play forcing developers to use their billing system.

In our app, for payment and product delivery purposes, we force authentication on "merchant's store account". We'd like to keep forcing authentication to avoid updating our whole delivery system backend.
Do you know if, like on iOS, Google will refuse our app for preventing "anonymous" purchases ? aka purchases from users with no merchant's store account.

I found no information in Google documentation, nor on forums about this subject.

Comment: On Android the buyer needs to have a valid payment method configured in the device's Google account.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question